# Can't login as root into MySQL container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file setup like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
  image: mysql:5.6
  volumes:
    - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - "MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database_name"
    - "MYSQL_USER=my_database_user"
    - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_database_password"
    - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_root_password"
  ports:
    - "33061:3306"
```

volumes:
    dbdata:

I'm trying to login to the mysql cli client with root user & password (by first going into the container itself):

```
mysql -uroot -pmy_root_password
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Probably you have a different local instance running at `3306` try passing `-P 33061`

Comment: I'm trying to login to MySQL from within the Docker container. So I think the only running instance is the one from the provider (official) image?

Comment: Try to change the definition of the environment vars as shown [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I just double checked and my definition seems to match? Or did I make a typo?

Comment: It's not double-quoted in the example and it's colon separated `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example`

Comment: Getting the same error after I changed it

Comment: I'm facing same error, can you share the fix please !?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I didn't set the mysql root password env var from the very beginning. I had to remove the created volume "dbdata" and run docker-compose up again. That fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How exactly do you do that? I have the same problem, but did not use any env files or params.

Comment: Deleting the volumes helped. `$ docker volume rm volume_name`

Comment: You save my day, this is what exactly happening to me. I created a docker mysql image a while ago and deleted it and then install it again but was not able to login using new root password which I set while starting the docker. I had to use the old root password to login because of the "volume" being same both the times.

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps:

1. stop the running containers: docker compose down
2. find the docker volumes: docker volume ls
3. remove the respective volume: docker volume rm volume_name
4. start the containers: docker compose up -d